# Find millions of items in big text file

Tags: vb.net

How can I find if a big string (more than 2 MB) contains any of a list of items?

I tried this

```
Dim Lit as New List (of String)
For x as Integer = 0 To 20000
    Lit.Add(x)
Next
If Lit.Any(Function(y) mytext.IndexOf(y, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) >= 0) Then
    'Code
End If
```

But it takes 10 seconds. How can I speed this up?

Comment: Can we see a copy of the text file?  Is it always going to be a list of x => y of integers you're cross comparing?

Comment: If List1 contains something from List2?

Comment: You would not be able to add `Integer` x to `List(Of String)`. `List(Of T)` are type safe.

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster. `Lit` is a hashset of the strings to search for in `mytext`. The `mytext` string is scanned only once starting at index 0. Substrings are extracted from `mytext` for all possible lengths of the search strings, and a hashset lookup is made for each substring.

```
Dim Lit As New HashSet(Of String)
For x As Integer = 0 To 20000
    Lit.Add(x)
Next
' Build a list of the lengths of the Lit strings.
Dim lengths As New HashSet(Of Integer)
For Each s As String In Lit
    lengths.Add(s.Length)
Next
Dim counts As List(Of Integer) = lengths.OrderByDescending(Of Integer)(Function(x) x).ToList
' Scan mytext from index 0, extract substrings of all possible counts, and see if the string is Lit dictionary.
For i As Integer = 0 To mytext.Length - counts.First
    Dim search As String = mytext.Substring(i, counts.First)
    For Each c In counts
        search = search.Substring(0, c)
        If Lit.Contains(search) Then
            ' Found search in mytext.
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: @Alex I saw that this is the second time you are asking this question. Providing more info about your problem would lead to a simpler and better solution. For example, are you always searching for integers? Are the integers in `mytext` separated by non-digits characters? In other words, if searching for `123`, and `mytext = "21230"`, should we say that `mytext` contains `"123"`? You really need to provide more info about your problem.

Comment: I have a big hash list its more than 20000  i want find it" big text" file its size  3mb< .now i want find how many hashs contain in "big text"file without form loop .. plese help 

Comment: @Alex - Please show example of hash, and part of big text file where hash appears.

Comment: @Alex - My solution could be simpler if hashes can be separated.

Comment: @Alex - Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just using .contains in a simple loop is virtually instantaneous on my ancient system and for the particular case starting with the high index (20,000) speeds it up even more.

```
Dim Result As Boolean = True

        For x As Integer = 20000 To 1 Step -1
            If Not MyText.Contains(Lit(x).ToString) Then
                'Console.WriteLine("Unfound:" & x.ToString)
                Result = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```